# fitnesse shows column header as surplus value

Tags: fitnesse

I get surplus mismatch values as result when I execute my fitnesse test. The surplus values are of the column header which match the number of rows I expect as result.

Also, the values are being shown as missing while they are correctly returned by my code. Please find below the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code for SmokeTestConfigReader. It is probably not returning the data in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

obvisously, the result has told that keys(field) of query table is not exsit[field xxx not present]. 
I think you should not add ? end of fields,example: [Name?] should be [Name]

you can refer the user guide: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.QueryTable